# Unable to bind values in new row in Dynamic mat table?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created dynamic mat table and having button to add the new row. I can able to add the new row as expected. But, If i enter the value in one row, the same value reflecting in other new rows as well. I think [(ngModel)] is not binding the values properly.

**component.html**

```
  <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="text-upper btnclr" (click)="AddNew()" style='margin-left:10px;color:white;float:left' [disabled]="!AddBillingInfoBtn">
       <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
   <span> Add New Row</span></button>

  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table" matSort>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>  {{ column }} </mat-header-cell>
                 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="item[column]">
                 </mat-cell>
         </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
               <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="element-row" >
          </mat-row>   
   </mat-table>
```

**component.ts**

```
 this.somedata = {id: "", name: "", amount: ""}
 testArr:any[];
 AddNew(){  
    this.testArr.unshift(this.somedata);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.testArr);
 }
```

**Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!**

Comment: I think it's important that you show how `somedata` is defined, and where it's coming from

Comment: @PoulKruijt I have updated the question with sample object

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new object reference for every element you push into the array, otherwise you just keep pushing the same object in there. To create a new reference, you can use the `spread` operator:

```
AddNew(){  
  this.testArr.unshift({ ...this.somedata });
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.testArr);
}
```

Comment: Working like charm. You saved my time. Thanks alot.